# Unique formula to sum values in various rows with one formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to find a single formula for cells in Column K, that will return the sum of cells in Column J up to when the row in col I was last TRUE. Can't seem to solve this puzzle. Any ideas?

Ive highlighted examples and what I am expecting to see in Col K as seen below

[image]

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: ms 365 desktop, version 2111

Comment: Does the data have headers? In such case you can apply a very simple formula. Also, what do you mean with a single formula? Do you want spilled results only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use IF to see if the Value is true they use sumifs to sum all the FALSE and then subtract what is already be accounted for.

Put this in K2 and copy down.

[image]

Comment: brilliant, thanks so much

Comment: This is a lot cleaner than mine

Answer (score 1):

`=--IF(INDEX(I:I,ROW())=TRUE,SUM(INDEX(J:J,MAX(IF(((I:I=TRUE)*(ROW(I:I)<ROW())>0),ROW(I:I)+1,1))):INDEX(J:J,ROW()-1)))`

For versions prior to Office 365 enter this as array formula (confirm with `ctrl+shift+enter`)

It checks if the cell in column `I` in the current row is `TRUE`.
If `FALSE` it returns `0`,
If `TRUE`, it returns the sum of the range in column `J` from the first row after the latest found `TRUE` in column `I` up to the current row -1 (if there's no prior `TRUE` in column `I` it starts from row 1).